# Restrict some users belongs to some email address

Tags: drupal-8

In my registration page, I don't want some users belongs to specific company will able to register my site. Instead of manually blocking that users, I want to block if any user tried to access my website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_registration which restrict the particular domain email address. I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Install restrict Domain registration module to restrict particular domain email addresses